# Why spring mvc store object in its own sessions

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

I am curious to know that why spring mvc store object in its own sessions when we submit a form. Will this cause any overhead or insecurity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring doesn't store anything in the session unless you tell it to. You have direct access to the session.

Session-scoped beans *can* go in some container inside the http session, but that's an implementation details, and it doesn't head an overhead or insecurity.